# Wordpress How can I make "abc.com " and "xyz.com/new" point to same page?

Tags: wordpress, cross-domain, subdomain, hosting

I have one Wordpress website (hosted on Godaddy managed hosting) and 2 domain names. Lets say abc.com [Primary domain] and xyz.com
How can I make abc.com and xyz.com/new point to same page?

Answer (score 0):

You could use this meta tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; URL='http://new-website.com'" />
```

There are lots of other ways to do it, but I think that's the easiest.